# Showing only TOP 1 value result from join duplicates

Tags: t-sql, join, sql-server-2008-r2

I have 3 tables like below. You will see how they are joined.

```
Orders Table  
+---------+------------+
| Orderid | LocationId |
+---------+------------+
| 36      | 14         |
| 38      | 13         |
+---------+------------+

OrdersDetails Table
+-----------+------------+
| Detailsid | OrderId    |
+-----------+------------+
| 38        | 36         |
| 39        | 36         |
| 40        | 38         |
+-----------+------------+

OrderLocations
+------------+------------+
| Locationid | DistanceKM |
+------------+------------+
| 13         | 550        |
| 14         | 245        |
+------------+------------+
```

When doing an inner join of the 3 tables we get:

[image]

I don't want to have a duplicate DistanceKM, ex. 245. I would like a 0 instead for line item 2 like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my solution:

Creating tables:

```
    CREATE TABLE #Orders
                    (
             Orderid INT, LocationId INT
                    );

INSERT INTO #Orders
VALUES
       (36, 14
       ),
       (38, 13
       );

CREATE TABLE #OrdersDetails
                           (
             Detailsid INT, OrderId INT
                           );

INSERT INTO #OrdersDetails
VALUES
       (38, 36
       ),
       (39, 36
       ),
       (40, 38
       );

CREATE TABLE #OrderLocations
                            (
             Locationid INT, DistanceKM INT
                            );

INSERT INTO #OrderLocations
VALUES
       (13, 550
       ),
       (14, 245
       );
```

The actual query:

```
;WITH cte
     AS
        (SELECT o.Orderid, d.Detailsid, l.DistanceKM, ROW_NUMBER() OVER
                                                                       (PARTITION BY l.DistanceKM ORDER BY o.Orderid
                                                                       ) AS rn
         FROM #Orders AS o
         INNER JOIN
         #OrdersDetails AS d
         ON o.Orderid = d.OrderId
         INNER JOIN
         #OrderLocations AS l
         ON o.LocationId = l.Locationid
        )
     SELECT cte.Orderid, cte.Detailsid,
                             CASE
                                 WHEN cte.rn > 1
                                 THEN 0
                                 ELSE cte.DistanceKM
                             END AS DistanceKM
     FROM CTE;
```

And here is the results:

[image]